# Sunspot / Solr / Lucene : Find similar article

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, morelikethis

Let's say we have a list of articles that are indexed by sunspot/solr/lucene (or any other search engine).

How can  be used to find similar articles with a given article?

Should this be done with a resuming tool, like:
http://www.wordsfinder.com/api_Keyword_Extractor.php, or termextract from http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console, or http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/demo.html ?

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122788/reducing-similar-top-results-in-solr-result-output/5123165#5123165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is very similar to the task I outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103457/apache-lucene-how-to-convert-collection-index-to-another-format/5104973#5104973).

In brief, you need to generate a summary for each document that you can use as the query to compare it with every other. A document summary could be as simple as the top N terms in that document (excluding stop words). You can generate top N terms from a Lucene document pretty easily without using any 3rd party tools, there are plenty examples on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=term+frequency+lucene) and the [web](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=lucene+document+term+frequency#sclient=psy&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=1o3&channel=cs&source=hp&q=lucene++term+frequency&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=7275f32320de49e3) to do this.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're looking for the [MoreLikeThis](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis) feature.